# Using vector bit-selects for conditional statements

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, vivado

I have the following SystemVerilog code below, and I'm unable to figure out how to make it synthesize. I believe my error is something related to the fact I'm using bit-select for my conditional statement, but I'm not sure what approach to take to make this work. I tried making a `wire` and a `reg` with a different name and replacing that with the inputs, but it didn't work. Any advice is appreciated.

```
module S(
input [15:0] DIN, 
input [7:0] PRBA,
input [22:1] VAD,
input SMCK,
output logic [31:0] CT2LIM,
);


always_ff @ (posedge SMCK) begin
      if (([21:15] VAD == [6:0] PRBA)) //issue is here, simply states I have a syntax error
            CT2LIM <= DIN;
            else
            CT2LIM <= CT2LIM;
        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets must be to the right of the signal name when you want to get a bit select.  Change:

```
  if (([21:15] VAD == [6:0] PRBA))
```

to:

```
  if ((VAD[21:15] == PRBA[6:0]))
```

This is the opposite of how you declare the signals in the port list.

---

You have another syntax error.  There should be no comma after the last port name.  Change:

```
output logic [31:0] CT2LIM,
```

to:

```
output logic [31:0] CT2LIM
```

---

You might get more helpful error messages when you compile your code on different simulators, such as the ones on edaplayground (if you sign up for a free account).